# What is the limit on the suggested edits queue?

Tags: support, review-queues

I noticed recently while I was fixing rotten/dead links was that the suggested edit queue was full, therefore I couldn't edit. What is the limit on suggested edits?

EDIT: Okay, it is getting really annoying because I can't edit/improve questions or answers. Please, just review the edits!

Comment: The number of items in the queue is currently 496 out of a maximum of 500

Comment: The queue is still full in Stack overflow (not meta)

Comment: that is because nobody wants a ban and got p... off

Comment: Seriously. You can get a edit ban? Okay, yes I understand that there are bad editors, but really, someone must review the suggested edits.

Comment: Yes, you can get an edit ban but nbk is referring to a **review** ban, which includes banning you from reviewing the suggested edits. I think most people are assuming the recent bans in Triage are the problem (even though that would mean a lot of the people messing up in Triage are at 2K+). Getting banned in one review queue gets you banned from all of them so if you get a Triage ban you can't review suggested edits.