# Why does the edit I made two days ago no longer show to me only?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

Two days ago I made an edit to this question adding that this will not format JSON unless it's in a `.json` file. After I made the edit it showed my edit to me only, until it gets reviewed, as it normally does. It seems incredibly unlikely that my review was denied in the last 2 days. Why?

[image]

[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

Comment: It was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26231158).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not totally wrong. You can nitpick but formatting JSON is a very common use case. This answer is high on google results. The question doesn't say what he's trying to format.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Formatting JSON should be though

Comment: @PhilipRego if you feel that updating that question is important I'd recommend asking separate question (here on meta) discussing that - comments on another question is not the right place to discuss that. Note that since the linked question is not specifically about JSON your proposed change should cover all languages. At the very least inlining most voted comment would be much better change (also OP indeed could have done it themselves if they deem it valuable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [suggested edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26231158).

You can view all of your suggested edits and their status by going to your Profile > Activity > All Actions > [Suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308453/philip-rego?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

As far as the [queue being full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397039/what-is-the-limit-on-the-suggested-edits-queue), this has been an issue recently. There's currently [a lot of bans happening](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving) right now, though I don't know how many 2K+ folks are getting caught in it, plus the general state of things mean fewer people are reviewing.

The queue being full doesn't have anything to do with the rejection.

Comment: Why does it say "Suggested edit queue is full". It should say "Your edit was rejected and we don't want you to make another edit to questions on this page. Post your own answer if you like."

Comment: @Philip The edit being rejected and the review queue being full today are separate issues.

Comment: @yivi Is it? If you click edit does it say the same thing? Edit: You're right I just checked it says I can edit again. Que must have been reviewed recently.

Comment: @Philip Users with more than 2K do not have to go through the review queue for edits. They can edit directly.